# Show alert if weekend is clicked in Gravity Forms datepicker (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity

I am using Gravity Forms with the date picker, and I need to show an alert if someone clicks a weekend. Here is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#input_2_3").datepicker({ // ID of the date picker field
        onClick: function (selectedDate) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var day = date.getDay();
            if (day === 6 || day === 7) {
                alert('you clicked a weekend!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that absolutely nothing happens, and no complaints from the console either.

What's going on? If it helps to know, my date format is dd-mm-yy

Comment: Consider that your code logic is wrong, then start debugging each line of your code and find out which line of code is failing your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You must use "onSelect" event. Look this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/0zdn8fh4/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ // ID of the date picker field
    onSelect: function () {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var day = date.getDay();
        if (day === 0 || day === 6) {
            alert('you clicked a weekend!');
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Edit, try adding one onchange, it should works:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#datepicker').datepicker();
     $('#datepicker').on("input change", function (e) {

        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var day = date.getDay();
        if (day === 0 || day === 6) {
            alert('you clicked a weekend!');
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Update: I fixed it - I had to place the script before the form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to place the script BEFORE the form. Problem solved.